# C# - Using Vim as Primary Editor

Tags: c#, vim

I've drunk the kool aid. Vim is elegantly beautiful, and I must learn how to use it and configure it to have a great compiler. Tis the best way to learn.

The question is, where do I start? Is there a good tutorial which teaches Vim for C# in Linux, yet one which assumes that you know next to nothing about Vi in general?

Massive kudos to anyone who can supply this one. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following instructions to set up vim for C#/mono in the past successfully:

[http://arun.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/c-and-vim/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114112215/http://arun.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/c-and-vim/)

Vim is actually quite good for c#.  Even does basic completion!

**Edit**: The original link was dead, replaced with a wayback machine copy.

Answer (score 2):

Look into these

1. http://kevin-berridge.blogspot.com/2008/09/vim-c-compiling.html
2. http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/04/23/using-vim-as-your-c-code-editor-from-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I love vim and for Studio work I use [viemu](http://www.viemu.com/).

Comment: I really wish it supported Vim plugins, like eclim.