# Can anyone suggest a nice vim plugin for C#?

Tags: c#, vim, plugins

I basically use vim to write some simple C# code snippets. Visual Studio is just too big and heavy for it. I am looking for a plugin that can highlight all the C# keywords and indent properly, code completion is good but not necessary. That's all, no big deal. I am considering I can write one for myself if I don't get what I want here.

Comment: No it's not, hence i posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Using Vim is Primary Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939266/c-sharp-using-vim-is-primary-editor)

Comment: I know you're trying to get away from Visual Studio, but there is a plugin that gives you Vim-style shortcuts for the VS editor called [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/).

Comment: ViEmu and VsVim are nice for Visual Studio, but I don't want the Visual Studio, it just don't worth for it and I love my vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Vim extension available for Visual Studio via the Extension Manager (Tools->Extension Manager) called VsVim.
I have not tried it myself however.

Comment: He wants a c# plugin for vim not a vim plugin for vs.